# Jquery open new page and redirect self page

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a requirement where if a user clicks a link, I want the current page to be redirected to the href attribute value at the same time open a new window with the current page link and an added param.

Jquery Script i have is the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$( "#clickMeDiv" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    refLink = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    location.href = refLink;
    window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '?param=1', "_blank", '', false);
}); 
});
```

and the HTML with the link is as follows:

```
<a id="clickMeDiv" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  Click Me    
</a>
```

This works okay on Chrome, firefox, Safari (Desktops) but opens an additional window in IE 8 and IE 11. I have not been able to test in other IE versions. my guess is it does behave the same in all IE.

You can also check the JS on http://jsfiddle.net/chirping/nmtkct26/1/

Also this works a little weird on Chrome on iOS although Safari on iOS works as expected.

Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: what this line should do? location.href = refLink;

Comment: redirects to the refLink

Comment: @SonaliKapoor can u try this?   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $( document ).on('click', '#clickMeDiv', function(e) {
      //e.preventDefault();
        refLink = jQuery(this).attr('url');
        window.location.href = encodeURIComponent('www.yahoo.com');
        window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '?param=1', "_blank", '', false);
    }); 
 }); also replace href='www.google.com' with href='#' and add another attribute url='www.google.com'. this is just a workaround.

Comment: @Sushil - Same problem now it opens the first window with current + #

Comment: so your link is now href='#' and url='www.google.com' right?? in jquery, I am picking the url attribute and not the href. did u miss that part??

Comment: Nopes i did pick up the URL attribute and now in IE two new pages open one with the current link + # at the end. and the second one is yahoo.com. Whereas the current page also remains open

Comment: hmm.. it seems to be something else then. I am trying to save this code in jsfiddle but everytime i try to update the fiddle, it clears up everything. let me try that again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76585/discussion-between-sushil-and-sonali-kapoor).

Comment: Good Morning @SonaliKapoor. u there?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `target="_blank"` from your html.

```
<a id="clickMeDiv" href="http://www.google.com" title="click me please">
Click Me    
</a>
```

Comment: tried that. but IE still opens two new windows one with the url in href and the other the same one with parameter. At the same time the current window is also left open and redirected to the href attribute url

Comment: would it be possible to come on chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript.  i can share the url where we have this issue.